# Strange outlook server setting

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am on a corporate (workplace) network and I've found the following mysterious setting in my Outlook configuration:

[image]

(Sorry for the German version - unfortunately I don't have any option to change that.)

On the "Server" line should stay a hostname. But there I can see a mail address there, with a 128-bit UUID before the '@' part. The domain part of this "mail address" is normal.

It is the preconfigured setting of the local system administration, and works, so it is probably not a bug.

What does this mean? Why don't stay a simple hostname there?

Comment: Have you asked your IT admins?

Comment: @DavidPostill No, it would be nearly hopeless to investigate, where they are. It is a big company.

Comment: @DavidPostill Another reason: it is only my personal curiosity, and isn't needed to my work. Thus I can't ask support from them in their paid work time.

Comment: No problem. You seem to have an answer anyway ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150540(v=exchg.150).aspx

> Second, Outlook clients no longer connect to a server FQDN as they
>   have done in all previous versions of Exchange. Outlook uses
>   Autodiscover to create a new connection point comprised of mailbox
>   GUID, @ symbol, and the domain portion of the user’s primary SMTP
>   address. This simple change results in a near elimination of the
>   unwelcome message of “Your administrator has made a change to your
>   mailbox. Please restart.” Only Outlook 2007 and higher versions are
>   supported with Exchange 2013.